# java block while run shell command using process

Tags: java, processbuilder, youtube-dl

I have a Java project which help to find all videos information in youtube playlist using youtube-dl. Here is the `Main.java`

```
import java.io.*;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String command1 = "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --flat-playlist --dump-single-json https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFcOH1YaRqUo1yEjY5ly09RFbIpUePF7G";
    String command2 = "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --flat-playlist --dump-single-json https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC6A0625DCA9AAE2D";
    System.out.println(executeCommand(command1));

}

private static String executeCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int exitCode = 0;
    String result = "";
    Process process;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").split(" "));
    builder.directory(new File("/tmp/test"));
    process = builder.start();
    exitCode = process.waitFor();
    return getStringFromInputStream(process.getInputStream());
}
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

The `command1` and `command2` are identical except for the Youbute playlist parameter. The playlist in `command2` has 409 videos and has 200 videos in `command1`. I can get result successfully for both command in terminal. Just the `command2` takes more time, but only  several seconds. But when I run the `Main.java` (javac Main.java; java Main), for `command1` it prints result successfully, but for `command2` it hangs there for several minutes without any result. Here is the `jstack` for this process

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f828c009800 nid=0xce7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8293cf7000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000771df9fe0> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:396)
    - locked <0x0000000771df9fe0> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess)
    at Main.executeCommand(Main.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

It hangs at `exitCode = process.waitFor();`. I have no idea about it. Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding a couple of breakpoints in your IDE and stepping through the code as it executes to see where it's hanging?

Comment: @KevinHooke I hang on exitCode = process.waitFor(); I just update the question and added the jstack.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and take the parsed command line  (after the replace all) then run it in shell and see if that works. Perhaps the final command renders wrong in your code.

Comment: just wondering... if you are not consuming the stdout of child process, the child process may block waiting if the buffer is full, right?  Ever tried to get the inputStream from process and keep consuming it?

Comment: If the problem really is a full output buffer, the easiest fix is to call [.inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) on the ProcessBuilder. That will send the output to the console instead of buffering it in memory (same for input and error streams).

Comment: @ AdrianShum  @tom Awesome!!! It works. I add builder.inheritIO(); then it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, by default the output of the subprocess is sent to a pipe which can be read using [Process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()). If the subprocess generates lots of output and the Java program doesn't consume it, the pipe's buffer will fill up and the subprocess will block on writing.

The easiest solution is to call [.inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) on the ProcessBuilder. That will send the output to the console instead of buffering it in memory (same for input and error streams).